# Separate class-library initialization for each client assembly

Tags: c#, class-library

I'm writing a set of plugins for a third-party application which are implemented as .NET libraries and are loaded on application start, so they are all in the same application domain. One of the libraries is a collection of utility classes and extension methods that are used by others (including plugins written by other people, so this is basically a meta-library).

**The problem is**: inside the utility library there is an initialization code that allows to set up things like plugin title and such; which are, obviously, should be set per-client, i.e. per library in that case. This, of course, cannot be achieved using a static configuration class, as there would only be the single instance of it within the domain.

I'm also not allowed to load this library dynamically inside other plugins into a separate domain; and that will be a waste of memory, which is a concern.

**The questions are**:

1. Is it even possible/reasonable to implement such per-client runtime configuration for other libraries?
2. If it is, what approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly, but you seem to be suggesting that there is an app which loads plugin-dlls at startup. You (the app developer and potentially plugin developer) want to provide a static class which has utility functions, that the plugins can use, without having to "re-invent the wheel" for every plugin. Below is my assessment (based on the above understanding)

- Your utility class seems to store plugin specific data - so by definition it cannot be static
- Yes, you can potentially load a plugin specific configuration file (file name **might** have to follow a naming convention to be effortlessly loaded by a static function) and offer the utility services - but I would say that is a bad design
- I would rather provide a utility which does not store any plugin specific data, but simply provides services based on method arguments. If you see yourself passing the same parameters a lot of times to the utility, then you should encapsulate those parameters into its own class/struct (like PluginData?)

**EDIT**

Let me expand a bit on the 3rd approach specified above:

You can represent your plugin configuration using a class, something like below, or you can get fancier.

```
class PluginConfiguration {
    public string PluginName {get; private set;} // This represents a property that all plugins share i.e. well known properties

    // all the configurations "private" to the plugin can go here
    // You might want to use some XmlDocument or a different data structure for this purpose
    public Dictionary<string,string> ConfigItems {get; private set;}

    public PluginConfiguration(string configFile) {
        // Load the configuration from the config file
    }   
}
```

Now your utility library can pass arguments or return data of type `PluginConfiguration` and help you centralize all repeating code for plugins

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The app is third-party, but otherwise you're correct. Unfortunately, your proposal is just the thing I was hoping to avoid. Alas, it does seem technically impossible, unless the reflection is used to trace method calls; which in its turn is impractical. A friend of mine, though, just yesterday proposed a similar solution, but without the need of passing actual data, which for all intents and purposes is static by nature: to implement sessions on the library side.

Comment: This will allow to pass the hard work of configuration parsing to the library, so that the clients wouldn't have to write almost identical code over and over again. And the only parameter that has to be passed is the configuration ID.

Comment: So I guess that would be my answer. Which I, of course, will formulate and post properly, not as comments.

Comment: @AllisTauri I have clarified the 3rd approach to make it more understandable. HTH